# How to plot line graphs with different x-range in one figure using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a dataset with 3 columns. For Example

```
ifile.txt
1     4    3
2     2    5
3     4    7
4     6    7
5     9    6
6     0    8
7     3    4
8     3    4
9     2    4
.     .    .
.     .    .
```

I would like to plot one line using 1:2 with x-range [3:7] and another line using 1:3 with x-range [5:9] in the same figure

I was trying to modify in plot command, but can't able to do.

```
plot\
 'ifile.txt' using 1:2 with xr [3:7],\
 'ifile.txt' using 1:3 with xr [5:9]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, if you need a common x-axis for both plots, you must filter the data in the `using` statement, and give all data points outside the desired range an invalid value, `1/0`:

```
f(value, left, right) = (value < left || value > right ? 1/0 : value)

plot 'ifile.txt' using (f($1, 3, 7)):2,\
     '' using (f($1, 5, 9)):3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the axes and tics separately. This should get you done:

```
set xrange  [3:7]
set x2range [5:9]
set x2tics  5, 1
set yrange  [3:10]
set y2range [3:10]
set y2tics  4, 9, 1

plot 'ifile.txt' u 1:2 axes x1y1, 'ifile.txt' u 1:3 axes x2y1 w lp
```

[image]