# gnuplot: change dashtype of line, depending on x-value

Tags: gnuplot

I want to draw a line, where x-values are defined by years. The actual values should be a connect by a solid line, but the forecast only as dashed line.

My data would be

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1980 | 5 |
| 1990 | 10 |
| 2000 | 17 |
| 2010 | 27 |
| 2020 | 39 |
| 2022 | 44 |
| 2030 | 60 |

To get the graph i use but of

```
plot 'input.dat' using 1:2 with lines dashtype 1
```

but of course, the whole line is solid.
Is there a way to define different dashtypes for a given xrange, e.g. something like

```
plot 'input.dat' using 1:2 with lines from 1980 dashtype 1 from 2022 dashtype 0
```

I think a possible solution would be to use multiplots and draw 2 lines, but that seems to be an overkill, maybe there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a simpler solution than multiplots with the help of [How to plot line graphs with different x-range in one figure using gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337394/how-to-plot-line-graphs-with-different-x-range-in-one-figure-using-gnuplot)

```
predicted(x) = (x >= 2022 ? x : 1/0)                                                                               
actual(x) = (x > 2022 ? 1/0 : x)                                                                                   
plot 'input.dat' using (actual($1)):2 with lines dashtype 1, '' using predicted($1)):2 with lines dashtype 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In gnuplot you have variable linecolor, pointtype and pointsize (check `help points`), but not (yet?) variable dashtype and linewidth.

However, you have **variable arrowstyle** for vectors.
With this, you can set different styles with different dashtypes, linewidths and linecolor, however, at the cost of some extra effort in the plot command. You can plot vectors from a starting point with some `dx` and `dy`. So, you have to calculate this `dx` and `dy` from the difference of the current (`x1,y1`) and the previous (`x0,y0`) point.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### mimic variable dashtype and variable linewidth
reset session

$Data <<EOD
x       y
1980    5
1990    10
2000    17
2010    27
2020    39
2022    44
2030    60
EOD

set style arrow 1 dt 1 lw 2 lc "web-green" nohead
set style arrow 2 dt 3 lw 4 lc "red"       nohead
set grid x,y
set key noautotitle

plot x1=y1=NaN $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x0):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0): \
          (x1-x0):(y1-y0):((x1>2022)+1) w vec arrowstyle var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]